# D3.JS Tool tip with a dot plot

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <h1>  Amount of money spent on gas in a week vs Distance from work(miles)<h1/> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Labels removed</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                fill: none;
                stroke: black;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .axis text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

            .d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">





            //Width and height
            var w = 1000;
            var h = 610;
            var padding = 50;




            //Static dataset
            var dataset = [
                            [63, 45], [60, 43], [10, 12], [95, 60], [30, 15]
                          ];

            /*
            //Dynamic, random dataset
            var dataset = [];                   //Initialize empty array
            var numDataPoints = 50;             //Number of dummy data points to create
            var xRange = Math.random() * 1000;  //Max range of new x values
            var yRange = Math.random() * 1000;  //Max range of new y values
            for (var i = 0; i < numDataPoints; i++) {                   //Loop numDataPoints times
                var newNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * xRange);    //New random integer
                var newNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * yRange);    //New random integer
                dataset.push([newNumber1, newNumber2]);                 //Add new number to array
            }
            */

            //Create scale functions
            var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, 100])         // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
                        .range([0, w]); 

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, 100 ])         // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
                        .range([h, 0]); 

            var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([5, 5])
                                 .range([5, 5]);

            //Define X axis
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                              .scale(xScale)
                              .orient("bottom")
                              .ticks(5);

            //Define Y axis
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                              .scale(yScale)
                              .orient("left")
                              .ticks(5);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Create circles
            svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return rScale(d[1]);
               });

                var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                .offset([-10, 0])
                .html(function(d) {
                return "<strong>dataset:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.dataset + "</span>";})
                 svg.selectAll("circle")



                   svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.dataset); })
      .attr("width", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.dataset); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.dataset); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)





                //X AND Y text
                svg.append("text")
                .attr("class", "y label")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("x", -175)
                .attr("y", 12)
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .text("Distance from work (Miles) ")
                .attr("font-size",'12pt')
                .attr("font-weight","bold");

                  svg.append("text")
                .attr("class", "y label")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("x", 700)
                .attr("y", 600)
                .text("Amount of money spent on gas in a week ")
                .attr("font-size",'12pt')
                .attr("font-weight","bold");
            /*
            //Create labels
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d[0] + "," + d[1];
               })
               .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
               .attr("font-size", "11px")
               .attr("fill", "red");
               */

            //Create X axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            //Create Y axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);


function type(d) {
  d.dataset = +d.dataset;
  return d;


}


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello im trying to add a tool tip to my circles. When I run the code I dont get an error in my console which makes me think that it works but it does not. I think im missing something simple but I am in general not sure. Would really appreciate any help on this issue. the var.tip part is where I think the biggest problem is at

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in the code:

1. the tooltip plugin should be bound to the data visualization, as documented in the [quick usage instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-tip#quick-usage):

> `/* Invoke the tip in the context of your visualization */`
>   `vis.call(tip)`

In your case, `svg.call(tip)` should be executed before the creation of the circles.

2. For some reason, the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners are attached to some rectangles (classed `circle`), instead of being attached to the circles.
3. The tooltips are filled using `d.dataset`, which is inexistent, hence `undefined`. Assuming that you want to display the `x, y` coordinates, `d` may be used instead.

The snippet below illustrates the fixes.

P.S. You may want to use a more recent version of d3 and of the tooltip plugin, in order to benefit from latest bug fixes and other enhancements.

```js
//Width and height
       var w = 1000;
       var h = 610;
       var padding = 50;
       
    
        
      
       //Static dataset
       var dataset = [
           [63, 45], [60, 43], [10, 12], [95, 60], [30, 15]
            ];
       
       //Create scale functions
       var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([0, 100])         // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
                            .range([0, w]); 
    
       var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                       .domain([0, 100 ])         // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
                            .range([h, 0]); 
    
       var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([5, 5])
             .range([5, 5]);
    
       //Define X axis
       var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
             .scale(xScale)
             .orient("bottom")
             .ticks(5);
    
       //Define Y axis
       var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
             .scale(yScale)
             .orient("left")
             .ticks(5);
    
       //Create SVG element
       var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);
    
    
    
           var tip = d3.tip()
                    //.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                    //.offset([-10, 0])
                    .html(function(d) {
                    return "<strong>dataset:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d + "</span>";})
                    
                     svg.call(tip)
                     
       //Create circles
       svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xScale(d[0]);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(d[1]);
          })
          .attr("r", function(d) {
            return rScale(d[1]);
          })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    
    
    
    
                       svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "circle")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.dataset); })
          .attr("width", 0)
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.dataset); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.dataset); })
    
    
        
    
    
                    //X AND Y text
                    svg.append("text")
           .attr("class", "y label")
           .attr("text-anchor", "end")
           .attr("x", -175)
           .attr("y", 12)
           .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
           .text("Distance from work (Miles) ")
           .attr("font-size",'12pt')
           .attr("font-weight","bold");
    
             svg.append("text")
           .attr("class", "y label")
           .attr("text-anchor", "end")
           .attr("x", 700)
           .attr("y", 600)
           .text("Amount of money spent on gas in a week ")
           .attr("font-size",'12pt')
           .attr("font-weight","bold");
      
            
       //Create X axis
       svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
       
       //Create Y axis
       svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
    
        
    function type(d) {
      d.dataset = +d.dataset;
      return d;
        
    
    }
```

```css
.axis path,
       .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
       }
       
       .axis text {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
       }
    
       .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
```